# Save formatted xml

Tags: simplexml, domdocument, line-breaks, formatted

Hi Can someone please tell me why this inst saving to my XML file? it doesn't return any errors but doesn't write to the file either? It might be silly so I apologize in advance

```
<?php

$pastor    = $_POST["Speaker"];
$title     = $_POST["Title"];
$link      = $_POST["podcasturl"];
$download  = $_POST["Download"];
$podcastid = $_POST["Podcastid"];
$pubdate   = $_POST ["Date"];

$filename = 'podcast.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
$xml->addChild('title');
$xml->addChild('pastor', $pastor);
$xml->addChild('title', $title);

function saveXMLFormatted($xml, $filename) {
    $savexml                     = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $savexml->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
    $savexml->loadXML($xml->asXML());
    $savexml->formatOutput = TRUE;
    file_put_contents($filename, $savexml->saveXML());
}
```

Comment: Check the error log for any php errors that get thrown. It could be as simple as the web server not having write permissions on the podcast.xml file. Is podcast.xml in the same working directory as this script?

Comment: You do not call the `saveXMLFormatted()`  function anywhere, so you are not saving anything.